# localStorage does not persist data on refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I am building a weather application that is based on React-Router in which I present forecast for five days on tiles. After hitting a tile, being actually React Router's Link, the user sees another component (Weather) that shows more detailed information about the chosen day. Consequently, the path changes to localhost:3000/w/:{dateId}. The problem is, however, if I refresh the page, it crashes as it does not have the data for the display. I incorporated localStorage into it:

When user types in the city name and hits enter:

```
    handleFormSubmit = () => {
    geocodeByAddress(this.state.address)
      .then(results => getLatLng(results[0]))
      .then(latLng => {
        const lat = latLng.lat;
        const lng = latLng.lng;
        this.setState({
          lat,
          lng
        });
        fetch(
          `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=${lat}&lon=${lng}&appid=${API_KEY}&units=metric`
        )
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => {
            const dataWeather = data;
            this.setState({
              data: dataWeather.list,
              refresh: false
            });
            localStorage.setItem("weather", JSON.stringify(data));
          });
      })
      .catch(error => console.error("Error", error));
  };
```

and two functions that are then called in componentDidMount:

```
   hydrateStateWithLocalStorage() {
    for (let key in this.state) {
      if (localStorage.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        let value = localStorage.getItem(key);
      }
      try {
        let value = JSON.parse(value);
        this.setState({ [key]: value });
      } catch (e) {
        let value = ""
        this.setState({ [key]: value })
      }
    }
  }

  saveStateToLocalStorage() {
    for (let key in this.state) {
      localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(this.state[key]))
    }
  }
```

This, however, does not function correctly, as when I refresh the page (being on specific /w/:dateId) the whole application crashes, even though if in Chrome DevTools under the Application tab it is being correctly displayed.

Is there something that I am doing wrong with the localStorage?

Comment: Can you console.log location before you write and before you read?

Comment: define `value` in `hydrateStateWithLocalStorage` at after `for` loop

Comment: @mplungjan, yes, it console logs the location that I searched for before

Comment: @Vivek, I'm not quite sure i know where do you mean to define it

Comment: Are they the same host and port?

Comment: @mplungjan Where should I look for this information?

Comment: Both localhost:3000?

Comment: @mplungjan yes, they both are

Answer (score 2):

Change the below function -

Issue : You've redeclared `value` inside `if` and `try` block.

```js
  hydrateStateWithLocalStorage() {
    for (let key in this.state) {
      let value = null;
      if (localStorage.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        value = localStorage.getItem(key);
      }
      try {
        value = JSON.parse(value);
        this.setState({ [key]: value });
      } catch (e) {
        value = ""
        this.setState({ [key]: value })
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I removed the declaration for value at the very beginning of the for loop, however the problem is still present

Comment: @llievredemars that's correct and comply with my answer, i just thought that you want to restrict to only json for values and else set it to empty string

Comment: @llievredemars then you've to check your initialise part of program as I've tested above function and it works as expected

Comment: That's right, but it still does not fix the issue of localstorage not really persisting the state